# ASP.Net MVC - What do Mocks do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mocking

I'm new to ASP.Net MVC - I'm reading an MVC book and the following code test pagination in a sample application in the book:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_Paginate()
{
    // Arrange
    // - create the mock repository
    Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new Product[] {
                      new Product {ProductID = 1, Name = "P1"},
                      new Product {ProductID = 2, Name = "P2"},
                      new Product {ProductID = 3, Name = "P3"},
                      new Product {ProductID = 4, Name = "P4"},
                      new Product {ProductID = 5, Name = "P5"}
                                                      }.AsQueryable());
    // create a controller and make the page size 3 items
    ProductController controller = new ProductController(mock.Object);
    controller.PageSize = 3;
    // Action
    IEnumerable<Product> result = (IEnumerable<Product>)controller.List(2).Model;
    // Assert
    Product[] prodArray = result.ToArray();
    Assert.IsTrue(prodArray.Length == 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(prodArray[0].Name, "P4");
    Assert.AreEqual(prodArray[1].Name, "P5");
}
```

The question is that what does `Mock` do? can't I pass the array of `Product` to the `ProductController` directly? why this round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically mock simulates instance of class which implements `IProductRepository` by introducing a proxy under the hood which has the same methods and properties which are defined in an underlying interface.

Following line of code setup results which will be returned as soon as get accessor of `Products` property will be called.

```
mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(...);
```

Regarding `ProductController`, 
I believe its constructor has argument of type `IProductRepository`, so to instantiate `ProductController` and test it you have to instantiate an instance of class which implements `IProductRepository` and pass it in Controller's constructor, mocking of the `IProductRepository` allows you to concentrate on testing of the Controller and do not care about any details of `IProductRepository` implementation. Mocking is the right way to simulate dependencies of class under the test having only an interface in hand. So you are testing `ProductController` and all dependencies are mocked.

Answer (score 4):

The notion of Mocks and their counterparts, stubs, are used when Unit Testing applications. In this case they are being used to setup fake data that the controller can use to test its behaviour. The notion of Mocks and Stubs can be a complications one to get your head around.

Try reading this article by Martin Fowler called [Mocks aren't stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html). When unit testing you don't want to make calls to the database or file system (or they would be integration tests) therefore we mock the call to the external dependency

in the instance of your test code above, the IProductRepository class is mocked as it may connect to the database. This means we can fake its behaviour and return the data we need to return to test the rest of the Action method

Comment: you may also want to read kzu's "Mocks, Stubs and Fakes: it’s a continuum"  http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/mocks-stubs-and-fakes-its-a-continuum/

Comment: @gerryLowry great resource link!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is using a mocking API (probably Moq) to create an mocked up implementation of that interface for testing purposes.  It is useful because sometimes the real objects will do things like connecting to databases or other resources that are not conducive to testing.

http://code.google.com/p/moq/